# nuSOAP library error when run in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap, nusoap

while running nusoap 0.9.5 i get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Attempt to modify property of non-object
>
> Filename: nusoap/nusoap.php
>
> Line Number: 4694

i found a patch while searching Dr. Google that supposed to solve this probem
[nusoap-version-0-9-5-attempt-to-modify-property-of-non-object-in-nusoap-php](http://www.noaheltzroth.com/nusoap-version-0-9-5-attempt-to-modify-property-of-non-object-in-nusoap-php/)

and even though it solved the problem while run not from inside CodeIgniter, while i do it came up with a new error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: nusoap/nusoap.php
>
> Line Number: 4693
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: nusoap/nusoap.php
>
> Line Number: 4695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately Noah Eltzroth from http://www.noaheltzroth.com/
helped me to solve this problem

after doing this

To fix this problem I modified line 4694 in nusoap.php from:

```
$this->schemas[$ns]->imports[$ns2][$ii]['loaded'] = true;
```

To this:

```
$this->schemas[$ns][$ns2]->imports[$ns2][$ii]['loaded'] = true;
```

if you still get the same error i got in the CodeIgniter, simply add @ operator to remove the errors

the script works even though it shows the error, it is fine to hide the error

```
if (! @$list2[$ii]['loaded']) {
    $this->schemas[$ns][$ns2]->imports[$ns2][$ii]['loaded'] = true;
    $url = @$list2[$ii]['location'];
```